# Navbar doesn't go all the way to the edges

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I just started to study layout. I'm using bootstrap. As always at the beginning, I ran into problems, which I have not been able to solve for 2 days.

[image]

I have two questions:

1. Why the navbar doesn't go all the way to the edges. How to solve it? The indentation did not produce the expected results.
2. Why is the button not working? I kind of did everything as expected. I mean the foloowing:

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        div {
            border: darkgreen 1px solid;
        }



        .li-center {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translatex(-50%);
        }
   

        nav .navbar-nav li a:hover {
            color: pink !important;
        }

        nav .navbar-nav li a {
            color: lime !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="container" style="margin:0px;">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark" style="background-color:darkblue;margin:0px;">
                <div style="margin:0px;">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img src="img/bug.png" height="30" alt="bug logo">
                    </a>
                    <span class="mr-auto" style="font-weight: bold;font-size:large;color:white">Instruction</span>
                </div>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myMenu">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color:lime"></span>
                </button>
               
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myMenu">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Lessons</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, dolor.
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-9">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore quo dolor odit magnam explicabo
                delectus enim reiciendis quis cum? Ab, officia accusantium totam vel mollitia nemo repellat laudantium
                animi, illum modi consequatur, ipsa aperiam blanditiis maiores fuga alias dicta enim dolores deserunt
                quidem suscipit fugit! Praesentium voluptatibus distinctio, laudantium adipisci quisquam perspiciatis
                consequuntur tempore, dignissimos error blanditiis aliquid nesciunt repellendus? Rerum ea molestias at
                repellendus illum veritatis consectetur quas possimus aperiam, itaque explicabo ducimus harum ullam unde
                placeat sunt nam laborum minima accusantium, provident hic non sed. Magnam doloribus aliquam, odit
                adipisci consequatur eligendi perspiciatis perferendis, quisquam voluptatum eaque ducimus?
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a proper bootstrap starter template.
I am adding a template along with your CSS.
I hope this will work :)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
        div {
        border: darkgreen 1px solid;
        }
        .li-center {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translatex(-50%);
        }
        
        nav .navbar-nav li a:hover {
        color: pink !important;
        }
        nav .navbar-nav li a {
        color: lime !important;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, dolor.
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-9">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore quo dolor odit magnam explicabo
                delectus enim reiciendis quis cum? Ab, officia accusantium totam vel mollitia nemo repellat laudantium
                animi, illum modi consequatur, ipsa aperiam blanditiis maiores fuga alias dicta enim dolores deserunt
                quidem suscipit fugit! Praesentium voluptatibus distinctio, laudantium adipisci quisquam perspiciatis
                consequuntur tempore, dignissimos error blanditiis aliquid nesciunt repellendus? Rerum ea molestias at
                repellendus illum veritatis consectetur quas possimus aperiam, itaque explicabo ducimus harum ullam unde
                placeat sunt nam laborum minima accusantium, provident hic non sed. Magnam doloribus aliquam, odit
                adipisci consequatur eligendi perspiciatis perferendis, quisquam voluptatum eaque ducimus?
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css:

```
#myMenu{
margin: -9px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your style:

```css
        *{
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
        }
```

It'll make your navbar go to the edges.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try for the navbar:

```
.container {
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
      }
```